# jquery get offset() of element in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I need to fetch the offset info for a submit button that is buried deep within an iframe in a div.  I want to position another element adjacent to the submit button after the iframe is loaded.  The iframe is loaded from the same origin as the containing page.

```
<div id="editBox">
  <iframe id="ifr" src="mysource">
      <html>
        <head></head>
          <body>
            <form id="dataForm" enctype="" method="POST" action="">
              <div>
                <table>  some form elements </table>
                <button id="submitButton" onclick="" type="submit">Save to file</button>
```

I've tried

```
$('#editBox').contents().find('#submitButton').offset();
```

and

```
$('#ifr').contents().find('#submitButton').offset()
```

But both return undefined.

I've also wrapped the .contents statements in a setTimeout to determine if the problem is that I'm checking before the iframe is loaded.  (if that had worked I'd add a loaded event handler),  but no change, result still undefined.

How can I get the position info I need?

Comment: It's not doable if the iFrame is from another origin and hasn't explicitly given your origin permission to access it

Comment: Thanks Izzey - the iframe is from same origin.  I've ammended the question.

Comment: Try `console.log($('#ifr').contents())` and make sure the data is what you expect

Comment: console.log($('#ifr').contents()) returns an object that has an offset() function.  console.log("#ifr").contents().find('#submitButton') also returns an object that has an offset function

Comment: Then `$('#ifr').contents().find('#submitButton').offset()` will work, as long as the code is called after the iFrame is loaded and the frames are on the same domain

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code in a `load()` function for the iframe.  This works just like the document ready function, or window load function:

```
$("#ifr").on("load", function(){
    var offset = $(this).contents().find('#submitButton').offset();
});
```